# Change UserPreferencesFilePaths using Python

Tags: python, scripting, customization

Does anyone know how to change the script directory in the user preferences using Python from command line?

I believe it has something to do with `bpy.types.UserPreferencesFilePaths`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: See the [Blender Python API Reference page for bpy.types.UserPreferencesFilePaths](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UserPreferencesFilePaths.html) and see if it hels

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
path = "/somepath"
context.user_preferences.filepaths.script_directory = path
```

Comment: thank you, that works for 2.77 and 2.78, have yet to try with 2.76, but my guess is it works for 2.76 as well